# cpp vector sort runtime error

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int max(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}
bool comp(const string &l, const string &r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max(l.length(), r.length()); i++) {
        if (i >= l.length()) return false;
        if (i >= r.length()) return true;
        if (l[i] < r[i]) return l[i] < r[i];
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    int N; scanf("%d", &N);
    vector<string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        string s; cin >> s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
    for (const string& s : v) {
        cout << s;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

In Educational Codeforces Round 9 held on yesterday, I couldn't solve the problem http://codeforces.com/contest/632/problem/C using sort with user-defined function.

I used stl vector containing string and it seems to work on some test cases, but it occurs runtime-error on following testcase.

100
abccaacaacacabbbcbbabcccccacabbaccbcacabcbbbaca
bbbaccbbccbbbcacaabbcccaabcbbcbbbacaacabc
cccabccaaabcaccabccbcccbbaacaaccbb
cccabccaaabcaccabccbcccbbaacaaccbbcb
cccabccaaabcaccabccbcccbbaacaaccbb
cccabccaaabcaccabccbcccbbaacaaccbbbcca
abbbcbbbbbbcccccbcbbb
bbbaccbbccbbbcacaabbcccaabcbbcbbbacaacabcb
abbcacbcabacccbcbabaabcaabcabacbbbbbca
cccabccaaabcaccabccbcccbbaacaaccbbcaa
cbcbbaccacbcababbccaacabacbcabbaccbcbcbcabbc
acbbbbbbbcabbcbcaccccbcbaacccaccabcbaac
bacccabacbbaaa

I can't view the full test input due to codeforces' policy. How do I defeat this situation?

Comment: The two length checks in your for-loop are redundant because of your loop's end condition (`i` will always be smaller than the length of both `l` and `r`). Then you only compare the first letter of `l` and `r` because you return immediately.

Comment: And you should probably fix the number for N...that was the reason why I was getting a timeout on ideone.com....

Answer (score 3):

Your `comp()` predicate doesn't handle the case where `l[i] > r[i]`.  So it returns 1 when comparing "foo" and "boo", and also returns 1 when comparing "boo" and "foo".  Therefore, it fails to implement a strict weak ordering (i.e., fails to behave like `<=`) , and the results of passing it to `std::sort()` are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use standard comparison method (not your own `bool comp(const string &l, const string &r)`), e.g.:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int N; 
    cin >> N;
    vector<string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        string s; 
        cin >> s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }
    std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<string>());
                                // or   std::less<string>()
    for (const string& s : v) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Or change your function to simple one, like:

```cpp
bool comp(const string &l, const string &r) {
    return l < r;
}
```

**Update:**

But if you really want to use your own `comp` function, you should understand that reason why exception `invalid operator <` occurs because your comparison function (`comp`) returns `true` when both relevant fields are equal (this not correct behavior for "less than" required for `sort`).

And at the end, small tip (it is hardly a solution) - try this for your code:

```cpp
bool comp(const string &l, const string &r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max(l.length(), r.length()); i++) {
        if (i >= l.length()) return false;
        if (i >= r.length()) return true;
        if (l[i] != r[i]) return l[i] < r[i];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's different from mine when you compare the string with the prefix of that, for example, "abcd" vs "abcdac". In the problem, you have to place the latter one before the former one.

Comment: As you mentioned, there isn't any problem using default function.